# auto&& return type from a C++ lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, auto, decltype

I'm interested to understand what exactly the trailing `auto&&` return type means, specifically as distinguished from `decltype(auto)`, which doesn't work here, and an unspecified return type, which also doesn't work.

In the code below, `fn` returns the `x_` field of the argument. When the argument is an lvalue, `x_` comes back as an lvalue, etc.

In the examples of `fn_bad[123]`, it seems to return `int`, even when an lvalue argument is provided. I can see why `-> auto` would cause this, but I expected `-> decltype(auto)` to return `int&`. Why does only `-> auto&&` work?

```
#include <utility>

struct Foo { int x_; };

int main() {
  auto fn_bad1 = [](auto&& foo) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(foo)>(foo).x_; };
  auto fn_bad2 = [](auto&& foo) -> auto           { return std::forward<decltype(foo)>(foo).x_; };
  auto fn_bad3 = [](auto&& foo)                   { return std::forward<decltype(foo)>(foo).x_; };
  auto fn      = [](auto&& foo) -> auto&&         { return std::forward<decltype(foo)>(foo).x_; };
  Foo a{};
  fn(a) = fn(Foo{100}); // doesn't compile with bad1, bad2, bad3
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but I expected -> `decltype(auto)` to return `int&`

This is expected behavior of [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype),

(emphasis mine)

> Inspects the declared type of an entity **or** the type and value category of an expression.
>
> 1) If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an **unparenthesized class member access expression**, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression.

So the result of `decltype(auto)` on `std::forward<decltype(foo)>(foo).x_` yields the type of the data member `x_`, i.e. `int`.

If you add parentheses as

```
[](auto&& foo) -> decltype(auto) { return (std::forward<decltype(foo)>(foo).x_); };
//                                        ^                                   ^
```

Then

> 2) If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and
>
> a) if the value category of *expression* is xvalue, then `decltype` yields `T&&`;
>     b) if the value category of *expression* is lvalue, then `decltype` yields `T&`;
>     c) if the value category of *expression* is prvalue, then `decltype` yields `T`.
>
> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as an ordinary lvalue expression, thus `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` are often different types.

Then, as you said, when pass an lvalue to the lambda the expression `(std::forward<decltype(foo)>(foo).x_)` is an lvalue, then the return type would be `int&`; when pass an rvalue the expression is an xvalue, then return type would be `int&&` (which might cause dangled reference trouble).

For the 2nd case, according to the normal rule of [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), whenever passed lvalue or rvalue the return type is always `int`.

The 3rd case is the same as the 2nd one.

For the 4th case, the special rule for [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) is applied, then the return type would be `int&` when the return expression is lvalue, and `int&&` when the return expression is rvalue.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! It's quite surprising to me that adding parentheses changes the return type, but I agree that is what the text seems to say.

Comment: @E_G This is how `decltype` works, yes it is confusing because it provides two independent features.